# System enters grub prompt rather than grub boot menu

Tags: grub2

After changing which of my drives connect to what SATA port, my system will always boot into a grub prompt, and then when I exit that prompt it will load the usual grub boot menu as expected.

Before fiddling the order of the SATA connections the system would always just show the grub boot menu when started. I'm not sure why the grub prompt started showing after only rebooting with a different SATA port for each of my two drives.

Both of my drives are perfectly visible after finally booting from the grub menu, so it's not the case that any of the ports are not working; both drives are accessible after the boot.

Do grub or UEFI actually care about which SATA port each drive is connect to, as far as booting is concerned? does the order matter?

Comment: Probably because your partition number  relating to the Ubuntu system drive has changed so you're booting to the wrong drive.

Comment: In your /etc/fstab, are you using UUIDs or /dev/sdxx? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`. Have you run a `fsck` on the drives?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happens because of stale information in UEFI boot settings which relates to which SATA ports have discs that contain bootable partitions ... I guess I should never switch SATA connections between drives again without intending to!

I had to modify which device should be used for boot in the UEFI Boot settings to solve.